# How can i produce error if no argument is given?

Tags: loops, if-statement

The object is to prompt the user with a question, (alphanumeric is to be entered), and if the user does not put anything in, it is supposed to produce an error stating "----> Entry is required", and loop back and prompt again, but i cannot figure it out...I took this working chunk from another program i made, any tips on how to format it to give an error to a null input?

```
    while [ true ]
    do

       echo -n "Enter course code: "
       read fact1
       chk_num=$( echo $fact1 | grep '^[0-9][0-9]*$' | wc -l )
       if [ "$chk_num" -eq 0 ]
          then echo
               echo "----> Entry is required"
               echo
          else break
      fi

    done
```

Comment: I don't quite get it: was is *exactly* the problem? I tested your snippet and it seems to that it does what you want. So, there must be something I'm no understanding...

Comment: So the code i pasted works IF i am trying to enter in a number, and giving me an error if i dont..what i am now trying to do, is tweak that code, so i if i dont give it text, then it will produce an error

It will prompt you saying "Enter course code: "
IF i do not put any text in, and just hit enter, i need it to return an error, but i dont know how to do that.